# Construct 98 % confidence level for the means?

Tags: probability, statistics

Can someone help solve these probability problems, I'm reviewing for my final.

1) Laptop computer prices were determined by sampling 7 stores. The prices were as follows: 500 700 650 550 800 600 750. Build a 98% confidence interval for the mean. The prices are normally distribute. Sigma is unknown.

2) Test the claim that the average SAT score for graduating high school students is more than 1100. A random sample of 64 students was selected, the average sat was 1145. Assume signma is 320 and alpaha is 0.10.

Please help solve these asap. Thank You

Comment: What are your thoughts on these?

Comment: I think I have to take get E(X) for the first one but I don't know what to do after for 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), you don't have the population $\sigma$, so you have to substitute with the sample data. Do you know how the mean is distributed when you use sample data for $\sigma$, instead of using the population $\sigma$?

For 2), you need to construct a $10$ % confidence interval (I don't know if it is 1-sided or 2-sided; does not seem clear from the statement.)  and see if $1100$ falls inside or outside the interval